# Epson perfection scanner 2580 Photo does not work with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, scanner, epson

My Epson scanner did not work with Ubuntu 12.04 so I upgraded to 14.04 but it's still not working

I read something about installing drivers

Does any one know how exactly?

---

Scanimag -L:device'snapscan:lib usb;001:003 is a Epson Scanner flatbed scanner.
could not find stringdescriptor:pipe error.
whatever that means!I have got from Ubuntuusers.de the following code:2

wget http://a1227.g.akamai.net/f/1227/40484/7d/download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/f/01/00/01/58/31/9d81f4deee448e0440c8bcd7af581c3e8a8b43b9/iscan-2.10.0-1.c2.i386.rpm
wget http://a1227.g.akamai.net/f/1227/40484/7d/download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/f/01/00/01/58/54/1899fd522665e4b1c80fe95252838994192d5207/iscan-plugin-gt-f500-1.0.0-1.c2.i386.rpm
when enter it i get at the place of the 3 a 9 in the SCANIMAG -L result,which is:device 'snapscan:lib usb:001:003 and from:SANE-FIND-SCANNER i get:could not fetch string descriptor,pipe error.I am an absolute beginner,but,or,because of that i think,that,when i could change the 9 to a 3 it should work?! But even if it should be right,i don't know how to do it!
Pease help me!

Answer (score 1):

[Status on sane](http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-backends-external.html).

> - Model: Perfection 2580 PHOTO
> - Interface: USB  0x04b8/0x0121
> - Status: Good
> - Comments: auto film loader not supported; requires DFSG non-free `iscan-plugin-gt-f500`; also supported by the [snapscan backend](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-backends.html); overseas
>     version of the GT-F550
> - Supported by the epkowa backend (iscan 2.29.1/iscan-data 1.23.0)

---

Best instructions I have found are in [an official PDF from Epson](http://support.epson.ru/upload/library_file/11/scanner_linux.pdf). These are for Redhat so all references to "rpm" need to be translated to the equivalent "apt-get" method though you can expect sane to already be installed.

Regarding installation of software refer to the "install by source" method in the PDF and download the "tar.gz" versions from their [website](http://download.ebz.epson.net/faq/linux/faq_ls_00007.html).

Comment: I typed:epkowa.co.jp/english/linux e/index.html,but it shows:server not found!

Comment: the same at:download.ebz.epson.net/faq/linux/faq_1s800007.html